# Drupal 7 - Entitiy Reference - Reference field to a conent as a link

Tags: entities, nodes

I created content - lets call it X - which has a field with the type of entitiy reference (done with [Entitiy reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)). This field refers to a content that can be selected via select list. When X is shown the reference field appears but not as a link so that I can directly forward to that content. Do I need any additional module for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the **Manage Display** page (Structure->Content Types->*Your content*), first be sure the display format is set to **Label**. Then, click on the gear on the right. You will see a checkbox with "Link label to the referenced entity". Check that and click Update, then save our display. The label will now link to the entity.